# amCharts 4 (v4) Display values instead of percentage in pie chart

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts

Once again exploring Amcharts V4 and i get to display legend in amcharts v3 with value numbers like this (believe is standard)

> "legend":{
>           "position":"left",
>           "fontSize": 22,
>         },

But in V4 in the documentation the session about Legend values isn't completed, and when i declare the standard is in percentage

> pieChart.legend = new am4charts.Legend()

[Image of a legend in Amcharts V3 and Amcharts V4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYcjN.png)

thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 6):

You can change template text in amCharts v4 pie chart by :

```
pieSeries.labels.template.text = "{category}: {value}";
pieSeries.slices.template.tooltipText = "{category}: {value}";
```

Answer (score 2):

what worked for me is passing in the value into the legend like so:

```
let pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.legendSettings.labelText = '{category}';
pieSeries.legendSettings.valueText = '{value}';
```

this assumes your data is something like

```
const data = [{
  category: "hotdogs",
  value: 33
}]
```